# How to skip retrieving dependencies in provided scope when retrieveManaged is true?

Tags: sbt

It seems that sbt always retrieves all the dependencies as long as I set `retrieveManaged := true` in `build.sbt`.

I have some dependencies configured as `provided`, and I don't need them to be retrieved into the directory `lib_managed/`.

How to tell sbt about that?

Comment: How do you trigger the download? What command/task do you use to have the deps downloaded to `lib_managed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After days of searching I found a sbt plugin which perfectly matches my requirement. https://github.com/xerial/sbt-pack.

Although it's not about lib_managed, it retrieves all the dependencies into target/pack/lib without those provided. And target/pack can be distributed directly without useless jars. That's exactly what I need.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you configured sbt-pack to copy (or symlink) non-provided dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

The intent of the `provided` module configuration is:

> This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

From [Maven's docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope) (SBT use Ivy, which reuses Maven's conventions in this case).

---

The intent of `retrieveManaged := true` is to:

> insulate your builds from the ivy cache being cleared

From [SBT's FAQs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Faq.html#Where+has+0.7%E2%80%99s++gone%3F)

---

As such I'd argue it makes sense that `provided` dependencies are still retrieved to `lib_managed` under `retrieveManaged := true`.

Perhaps you want to look at [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) as a way to bundle your application (including dealing with `provided` dependencies) instead of using `retrieveManaged`.

Comment: Thanks. I see why this happens. But I'm still stuck in the situation: When I deploy my project, I call `sbt package`, and archive all jars from lib_managed. The problem is, for example I'm working on an spark project, and spark-core itself depends on quite a lot of jars, which are never used in the runtime environment. I don't want to archive those jars into my deploy package which make my package bloated. Any suggestions?

Comment: I've no experience with Spark, but it looks from a little googling like you might want sbt-assembly. It talks a little about specifically provided and Spark: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files

Comment: thanks. sbt-assembly do can exclude provided dependencies. It's great and solves my problem more or less, however it produces a fat jar which is not exactly what I want.